# php compare 01 to 1 from datetime object

Tags: php, datetime, compare, leading-zero

DateTime object outputs 01, 02, 03 etc when I
use

```
$num = $dt->format('d');
```

to get the day number

Then I compare the $num value if it's
the first day of the month like so:

```
if ($num == 1)
```

but the $num value is '01'.

Now php compares it as expected

```
var_dump($num == 1)
```

returns **true**

I was thinking, should this be enough for me
or I should enclose the $num variable with an intval
like so:

```
intval($num)
```

this way if it is 01 it will display '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `$num = $dt->format('d')` returns a String.
If you have `==` as a *Comparison Operators* and the two values are not from the same data type, PHP try to match them.
So in your case (`$num == 1`) you are comparing a String with a literal Integer
Therefore PHP is trying to converting the Sting into a Integer (only for the comparison).
In the end you are already comparing two Integers.
The type conversion does not take place when the *Comparison Operator* is `===` or `!==` as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.
So with `$num = '1';`, a comparison like `$num === 1` would always return false.
If you like to strip of leading zeros but don't convert the data type, I would use:
 `$num_as_str = ltrim($num,'0');`
If you like to convert the variable to an Integer use this:
`$num_as_int = intval($num);`

[From the PHP manual:](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

> **String conversion to numbers**
>
> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value and type are determined as follows.
>
> The string will be evaluated as a float if it contains any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E'. Otherwise it will be evaluated as an integer.
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

Comment: Yes I was assuming php was making a comparisson. Yes I don't care to keep the date num as a string. So I better convert it just to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything written by Webdesigner is right, but you can simply get the day number without leading zero by 'j' parameter:

```
$num = $dt->format('j');
```

So you can compare it with an ordinary numbers without any explicit type cast.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it.